# Force GeoServer SRID 0

Tags: postgis, srid

I'm developing a GIS solution which uses only geometry data. I designed my spatial DB with PostGIS and now I'm performing some trials connecting the DB with GeoServer map server (using the administration page).

In the layer definition of the administration tool there is the mandatory field SRS(Spatial Reference System) to set with the appropriate SRID

I'd like to know which is the default SRID value to set in order to take into account the geometry type. I read that should be 0, but it doesn't work...

Comment: what projection is your data in?

Comment: I must visualize spatial data on a flat plane (not referenced with the world), i.e. the position of some defects on flat steel surface. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

GeoTools (and GeoServer) provide EPSG:404000 for generic 2D systems. Search for GENERIC_2D in http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/crs.html for details.

I've never tried to use it myself but I think it should do what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is that I was looking for! Regards. Nico